# getting error while configuring a new Authentication Filter of keycloak on geoserver (trying to integrate keycloak SSO with geoserver)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, keycloak, geoserver

[image]

getting above error kindly help with this

```
(

org.geoserver.security.validation.FilterConfigException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "verify-token-audience" (class org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.AdapterConfig), not marked as ignorable (40 known properties: "ssl-required", "cors-allowed-headers", "register-node-period", "redirect-rewrite-rules", "turn-off-change-session-id-on-login", "truststore", "client-key-password", "token-store", "resource", "realm", "proxy-url", "disable-trust-manager", "bearer-only", "autodetect-bearer-only", "truststore-password", "use-resource-role-mappings", "client-keystore", "confidential-port", "enable-pkce", "auth-server-url", "cors-allowed-methods", "public-client", "expose-token", "token-minimum-time-to-live", "min-time-between-jwks-requests", "ignore-oauth-query-parameter", "cors-max-age", "enable-cors", "allow-any-hostname", "realm-public-key", "credentials", "principal-attribute", "always-refresh-token", "policy-enforcer", "public-key-cache-ttl", "connection-pool-size", "client-keystore-password", "enable-basic-auth", "cors-exposed-headers", "register-node-at-startup"\]) at \[Source: (ByteArrayInputStream); line: 6, column: 32\] (through reference chain: org.keycloak.representations.adapters.config.AdapterConfig\["verify-token-audience"\])

)
```

(geoserver 2.23.0) and (keycloak 2.21.1)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 0):

First, I want to point out that the Geoserver community keycloak extension/plugin doesn't support newer keycloak as it tries to reach keycloak with url ..."/auth/admin/realms/"... [src code for url builder](https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/blob/main/src/community/security/keycloak/src/main/java/org/geoserver/security/keycloak/KeycloakUrlBuilder.java#L27) (the version was 2.25 when writing this answer)

As for your error, you need to remove "verify-token-audience" parameter from the Keycloak OIDC JSON adapter config that you exported from keycloak UI.

As for using a newer keycloak version, you could use Geoserver community plugin oauth2-openid-connect-plugin. It's more universal and not as advanced in implementing roles from keycloak into geoserver, but it works. [oauth2 tutorial](https://docs.geoserver.org/main/en/user/community/oauth2/index.html)